# Warning is not displayed in Xcode Issue Navigator

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

My project builds with a warning, but it is not displayed in the "Issue Navigator". How can I get to this warning so I can resolve it? I've tried clicking on the warning on the top of the window but that does nothing. I'm using Xcode 4.3.

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but "No Filer Results" indicates that this output is filtered somehow?

Comment: It is possible that Xcode has screwed up when it counted the number of warnings you had.  I had this happen multiple times.  If you can[t find the yellow warning, ignore it.

Comment: I went through the the build setting and switched on the compiler warnings for the different options to see if it would show up, but it turns out that those switches filter the warnings in such a way they they won't show up in the count at all if switched off so it must be something else. There must be some list or file I can look at to see this warning.

Comment: I get the same XCODE 4 bug:  After I began using XCODE4, for several days it showed red failures in the Warning tab of the left-hand nav pane ok; I'd click on them to go to the error.  But all of a sudden, failures no longer displayed, just "No Filter Results".
It is very hard to locate errors now.  I restarted computer, no effect.

Comment: I got it fixed by just closing the Xcode window.  There was another one behind it, and it shows the warnings tab ok.

Answer (score 14):

I met the same problem, and I found it simply because there are some thing wrong with the below filter input. 
You can solve the problem by typing something in the below filter input and then clear it.

Comment: Mine was filtered by errors... but could not notice that... thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Building on Yingpei Zeng's answer, the buttons on the bottom right of the 'grey' panel with the 'No Filter Results' message act as toggle switches to apply or remove filters. They are the buttons in this figure here on the bottom left (the clock and the two to the right of it):

[image]

Unfortunately, the buttons do not change much when toggled so you may miss that one has been accidentally hit...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and for me it helped to go to Xcode->Preferences->Locations and delete everything in folders of Derived data, Snapshots, Archives.  Clean project, build, and warnings and errors was back in Issue navigator.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my test project. And no solution mentioned above works. Finally I figured it out because the target project I selected is not the "Test" project. I was running test of each individual test. And the scheme I selected at that time is non-test project scheme. After I select the scheme for Tests, then the error in test project shows.

Comment: this is great, thanks & it led me to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5299#issuecomment-235981319) by [Michael Kirk](https://github.com/michaelkirk) that enables all warnings to show in any scheme as long as you add the other schemes in your workspace as outlined by Michael (he's talking about pods, but you can add other projects too)

Comment: @lukkea thanks for the github comment link, good to know. I just modified my scheme to include test project. Now I can know earlier if I break something in the test :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by going into **Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations** and changing the location of derived data to **Default**. (Not sure how it became undefaulted)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Kirby Todd for me it worked to clear the contents of the derived data folder (you can find the path as Kirby said by going to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly for me, in XCode 7.2 the correct answer was to quit XCode and restart it. Ugh.